# Why can not connect to master when running application on yarn-cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

My test codes are as below:

```
object WordCount extends App{
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount").setMaster("spark://192.168.1.101:7077").set("spark.driver.host","192.168.1.101")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
sc.addJar("/home/lost+found/FromWindows/untitled/out/artifacts/untitled_jar/untitled.jar")
val file=sc.textFile("hdfs://192.168.1.101:9000/Texts.txt")
val count=file.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
val res =count.collect()
res.foreach(println(_))
}
```

When I run this on local mode(set master as "local"),it is OK.When set master to "spark://ip:port",I got the following error message:

```
16/04/24 23:13:40 WARN MetricsSystem: Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
16/04/24 23:13:40 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://192.168.1.101:7077...
16/04/24 23:13:41 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@192.168.1.101:7077] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated] 
16/04/24 23:14:00 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://192.168.1.101:7077...
16/04/24 23:14:00 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@192.168.1.101:7077] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated] 
16/04/24 23:14:20 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://192.168.1.101:7077...
16/04/24 23:14:20 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[appclient-registration-retry-thread,5,main]
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@1bdfd28 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@376ed0[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2048)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
...
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
16/04/24 23:14:20 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
16/04/24 23:14:20 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

I have googled for some information,and there are several solutions.I tried for some,and I thought it may be something wrong with this set("spark.driver.host","xxx"),I have no idea about how to set the value of "spark.driver.host"(this is only what I thought,so may be wrong).
Here are my relevant configurations:

1./etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
#::1         SparkWorker
192.168.1.117 sparkmaster
192.168.1.101 sparkworker
192.168.1.103 sparkworkers
```

2./etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=00:21:9B:09:C6:0A
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=e25f58e9-2ebb-42b8-938b-2b6cc28736e3
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
IPADDR=192.168.1.101
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
DNS1=192.168.1.1
```

3./conf/spark-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/Spark/scala-2.10.4
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/Spark/hadoop-2.5.2
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/Spark/hadoop-2.5.2/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="-Dspark.history.ui.port=18080     -Dspark.history.retainedApplications=3 -Dspark.history.fs.logDirectory=file:///usr/local/Spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.4/logs"
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=192.168.1.101
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=2g
```

4./conf/slaves

```
sparkmaster
sparkworker
#sparkworkers
```

Any advise about how to solve this problem?Really thanks.

Comment: did you started properly the master and the workers? Can you see them on the UI at port 8080? Moreover, in the title of the question you asked for the yarn-cluster mode... but here in the body of the question you're using the standalone mode... what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: How are you submitting your spark job? could you put the `spark-submit` command that you are using? It seems that the question is about Yarn, but I could not see that you have submitted your job to any Yarn cluster

Comment: T.T sry about my bad description. I have just fixed the problem and then find another new trouble.The main reason is about akka built in Spark.I have changed /etc/hosts to: `127.0.0.1   localhost 
192.168.1.117 sparkmaster
192.168.1.101 sparkworker
192.168.1.103 sparkworkers`.    and then changed my codes as `val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount").setMaster("spark://sparkmaster:7077")`.I have tried set master as "spark://ip:port" which gets the same error above.Akka built in Spark requires only hostname is permitted(this is really not good).Thank @mark91 and @user1314742.